# Ruby one liner to pass arrays elements into a string with separator

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
myarray = ['value1','value2','value3']
```

And I'm looking for a one element array like this:

```
mynewarray = ['value1|value2|value3']
```

I know how to do that using each and concatening in a string, but I'm wondering if there is a oneliner and beautiful Ruby way of doing so...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the Array#join method.

```
 myarray.join('|')
```

[Array#join doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join):

Returns a string created by converting each element of the array to
a string, separated by sep.

```
[ "a", "b", "c" ].join        #=> "abc"
[ "a", "b", "c" ].join("-")   #=> "a-b-c"
```

Comment: This answer will provide the string, but not return it in a single-element array.

Answer (score 4):

Howsabout...

```
mynewarray = [myarray.join('|')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
[myarray.join('|')]
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try next:

```
[myarray.join("|")]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[ "a", "b", "c" ]*'|']
```

will output

```
["a|b|c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"aa|bb|cc".scan(/[^\|]+/)
```

will output

```
["aa", "bb", "cc"]
```

with Ruby 1.9.x